# Used fork –join pool for thread management, and set the thread count to 1200, so after an extend its behaving like a single threaded program

Tags: java, multithreading, nio, forkjoinpool

We are inserting to database a directory of 9 Million objects (files + folders). We are using a multithreaded version of Java8 NIO2 Files.WalkFileTree version.

Problem (Where we really need help is) 
We use fork –join pool for thread management. The MAX number of threads is set to 1200.
-   Initially in the preVisitDirectory – the threads are created for the parent directory and thus increasing the thread count.
-   Once the thread count reaches 1200. No new threads are created.
-   Thus essentially in an unbalanced File Tree – the logic boils down to a single threaded File tree traversal from a certain point.
-   The threads created for the parent directory just sit and wait till the child directory returns. Which is a wastage.
-   Thus after an initial high rate (and as well high CPU usage) there is a drop in rate.

Comment: you have to show the actual code

Comment: So what was the point of this story? That using a `ForkJoinPool` is useless if you don't actually have properly recursive tasks? Are you asking a question or giving a warning to others?

Comment: @Kayaman ...am just asking is there any alternative is present to perform this task ?

Comment: How about a regular threadpool?

Comment: Why not a regular thread-pool ?

Comment: In order to make it faster comparatively ..